# Data changes while interpolating data frame using Pandas and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I am trying to calculate degree hours based on hourly temperature values.
The data that I am using has some missing days and I am trying to interpolate that data. Below is some part of the data;

```
2012-06-27 19:00:00 24
2012-06-27 20:00:00 23
2012-06-27 21:00:00 23
2012-06-27 22:00:00 16
2012-06-27 23:00:00 15
2012-06-29 00:00:00 15
2012-06-29 01:00:00 16
2012-06-29 02:00:00 16
2012-06-29 03:00:00 16
2012-06-29 04:00:00 17
2012-06-29 05:00:00 17
2012-06-29 06:00:00 18
....
2014-12-14 20:00:00 1
2014-12-14 21:00:00 0
2014-12-14 22:00:00 -1
2014-12-14 23:00:00 8
```

The full code is;

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
filename = 'Temperature12.xls'
df_temp = pd.read_excel(filename)
df_temp = df_temp.set_index('datetime')
ts_temp = df_temp['temp']
def inter_lin_nan(ts_temp, rule):
    ts_temp = ts_temp.resample(rule)
    mask = np.isnan(ts_temp)
    # interpolling missing values
    ts_temp[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask),ts_temp[~mask])
    return(ts_temp)
ts_temp = inter_lin_nan(ts_temp,'1H')
print ts_temp['2014-06-28':'2014-06-29']
def HDH (Tcurr,Tref=15.0):
    if Tref >= Tcurr:
        return ((Tref-Tcurr)/24)
    else:
        return (0)
df_temp['H-Degreehours'] = df_temp.apply(lambda row: HDH(row['temp']),axis=1)
df_temp['CDD-CUMSUM'] = df_temp['C-Degreehours'].cumsum()
df_temp['HDD-CUMSUM'] = df_temp['H-Degreehours'].cumsum()
df_temp1=df_temp['H-Degreehours'].resample('H', how=sum)
print df_temp1
```

Now I have two questions; while using `inter_lin_nan` function, it does interpolate data but it also changes the next day data and the next data is totally different from the one available in the excel file. Is this common or I have missed something?
Second question: At the end of the code I am trying to add hourly degree days values and that is why I have created another Data frame, but when I print that data frame, it still has NaN number as in the original data file. Could you please tell why this is happening? 
I may be missing something very obvious as I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use numpy when pandas has its own version.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df  =df.asfreq('1d') #get a timeseries with index timestamps each day.
df['somelabel'] = df['somelabel'].interpolate(method='linear') # interpolate nan values
```

Use as frequency to add the required frequency of timestamps to your time series, and uses interpolate() to interpolate nan values only.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this method does the same. The values on 29-06-2012 (the day after the missing day) are not the same as the actual data. This interpolation is supposed to change/add the missing day (hourly values) not to alter other days as well. Is this the behaviour that I should expect?